# download image using perl script

Tags: image, perl, download

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
my $ctime       = time();
my $Home_page   = 'www.condortk.com/';
my $output_file = "www.condortk.com-$ctime";
my $url         = 'http://www.condortk.com/results.php?keyword=&Buscar.x=4&Buscar.y=7';
my $m           = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$m->get( $url ) or die "unable to get $url";
my $Home_Con = $m->content;
system( 'mkdir Images' ) if ( !-d "Images" );
my $next = '';
my $page = '';

while ( $Home_Con =~ m/<div class="producto"><a href="([^>]*?)"/igs ) {

#print "Loop 1\n";
  $m->get( $1 );

  my $list_content = $m->content;
  my $img_name     = '';
  my $img_folder   = '';
  my $image        = '';
  my $big_image    = '';

  while ( $list_content =~ m/<div\s*class="nombre2"><a\s*href="([^>]*?)"/igs ) {

#print"Loop2\n";
    my $desc  = '';
    my $desc1 = '';
    my $block = $Home_page . $1;
    $m->get( $1 );
    my $content1 = $m->content;
    if ( $content1 =~ m/id="imgproducto"><img src="([^<]*?)"/is ) {
      $img_name = $1;

#   print "$img_name\n";

      if ( $img_name =~ m/\/\w+\/\w+\/([^>]*?)$/is ) {
        $img_folder = $1;

#print "$img_folder\n";
#print "$Home_page.$img_name\n";
        getstore( $Home_page . $img_name, $img_folder );

      }
    }
  }
}
```

i am trying to download and save a specific images from the site. but i am not sure why i am not able get those images. I have used the right regular expression of the images.The part which i have doubt is getstore method.Need some guidance.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expressions work because of luck, they are not solid. See the 'wrong regex' comments. Also, the *getstore(url, file)* method needs http://host.org/dir/file as argument 1 and *path/to/file.jpg* as argument 2.

Here is a working version:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
my $ctime       = time();
my $Home_page   = 'www.condortk.com/';
my $output_file = "www.condortk.com-$ctime";
my $url         = 'http://www.condortk.com/results.php?keyword=&Buscar.x=4&Buscar.y=7';
my $m           = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$m->get( $url ) or die "unable to get $url";
my $Home_Con = $m->content;
system( 'mkdir Images' ) if ( ! -d "Images" );
my $next = '';
my $page = '';

while ( $Home_Con =~ m/<div class="producto"><a href="([^"]*?)"/igs ) { # <-- wrong regex

  #print "Loop 1 $1 \n";
  $m->get( "http://www.condortk.com/$1" ); # <-- wrong url

  my $list_content = $m->content;
  my $img_name     = '';
  my $img_folder   = '';
  my $image        = '';
  my $big_image    = '';

  while ( $list_content =~ m/<div\s*class="nombre2"><a\s*href="([^"]*?)"/igs ) {

    #print "Loop 2 $1 \n";
    my $desc  = '';
    my $desc1 = '';
    my $block = $Home_page . $1;
    $m->get( $1 );
    my $content1 = $m->content;
    if ( $content1 =~ m/id="imgproducto"><img src="([^<]*?)"/is ) {
      $img_name = $1;


    # wrong url and 'save as' parameters
    if ( $img_name =~ m/\/\w+\/\w+\/(.*)$/is ) {
        my $basename = $1;
        my $get = "http://${Home_page}${img_name}";
        my $save = "Images/$basename";
        my $code = -1;
        if ( ! -f $save ) { 
            $code = getstore($get, $save ); 
            print "$get --> $save : $code\n";
        } else {
            print "Skipping $save\n";
        }
        #if ($code != 200) { print "$get --> Images/$save : $code\n"; }
    }

    }
  }
}
```

-

```
$ perl dl.img.pl
http://www.condortk.com/.../60504s_725x0.jpg --> Images/Images/60504s_725x0.jpg : 200
http://www.condortk.com/.../60508s_725x0.jpg --> Images/Images/60508s_725x0.jpg : 200
http://www.condortk.com/.../60501s_725x0.jpg --> Images/Images/60501s_725x0.jpg : 200
http://www.condortk.com/.../60020s_725x0.jpg --> Images/Images/60020s_725x0.jpg : 200
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but could you please tell me the use of the code.

  





 `#if ($code != 200) { print "$get --> Images/$save : $code\n";`

Comment: Previously, when the script tried to get *www.moo.com/dir/img.jpg*, the server returned 400 (Bad Request) because the address was not prefixed with *http://*. You can use the return code to figure out what went wrong or to assert that the server understood the request.

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching images, use the specific [image-methods at WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#IMAGE-METHODS) that may helps you to reach what you are looking for.
Example:

```
my @images = $mech->find_all_images( url_regex => qr/productos-detalle\.php/ );
```